# Solving for a set with limits on final set size

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a finite subset $A$ of the interval $[0,1]$, find a smallest set $B$ such that $B$ is a proper subset of $A$, and for any $a$ in $A$, there is a pair of unique values $b_1$ and $b_2$ in $B$ such that $b_1 \times b_2 = a$.

For example, given

$$ A = \{0.125, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9\} $$

A possible (but probably not smallest) solution for $B$ is

$$ B = \{0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9\} $$

This satisfies the initial problem, because $0.25 \times 0.5 = 0.125$, allowing us to recreate the original set $A$. The length of $B$ is smaller than that of $A$, but I’m guessing there are smaller answers as well.

I assume that the solution space for $B$ is large, if not infinite. If a solution exists, how would a smallest set $B$ be found?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks for updating the tags - I wasn't sure which one was better. May I ask why this gets a downvote? I want to be sure to ask good quality questions, and I'd love advice if there's a better way to approach it.

Comment: I don't even know if the elementary set theory tag is appropriate. I just can't place this question in a different tag. Although the revised one is clearer, maybe someone will come up with some idea. Perhaps some real analysis or something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a restating of your question:

Given a finite subset of the interval [0,1], find a smallest set B (or prove no such set exists) st. B is a proper subset of A and for any a in A, there is a pair of unique values b1 and b2 in B such that b1*b2 = a or a is present in B. Here we mean smallest to be having the least number of elements.

Assuming I have understood your problem correctly, such a B will always exist (in particular let B = A), however if you require that B be a proper subset of A (that is, its a subset that is not equal to A), then a solution may or may not exist. An easy counter example would be any singleton set, because the only proper subset is the empty set.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Yes, I believe you have it stated perfectly, and very succinct! And yes, I intended for B to be a proper subset of A. The singleton set is a good example where there is no solution.

Comment: And yes, by optimal I mean smallest - I’ll clarify that in my question

Comment: I may reword your rewording to something like this: Given a finite subset A of the interval [0,1], find the *smallest* set B st. B is a proper subset of A, and for any a in A, there is a pair of unique values b1 and b2 in B such that b1*b2 = a. (Thoughts?)

Comment: that sounds good to me, as for an algorithm I'm still not sure, but I'll think about it. I would like to add however that the notion of "the" smallest subset is not well defined as there may be multiple smallest subsets. Instead you might try "a" smallest subset

Comment: I've revised the question so that it's clearer, based on our discussion